# invalid parent values when using dcat in JAGS

Tags: python-3.x, jags

I can't get JAGS to initialize the model

```
import pyjags

jags_model = '''
    model {

        pmf[ 1 ] <- .25
        pmf[ 2 ] <- .25
        pmf[ 3 ] <- .25
        pmf[ 4 ] <- .25

        test ~ dcat( pmf[] )
    }
'''

jags_data = dict()
jags_model = pyjags.Model(jags_model, data=jags_data, init=dict(test=1), chains=2)
jags_samples = jags_model.sample(100, vars=['test'])
```

When initializing this model in python using *pyjags*, I get

```
JagsError: Error in node test
Invalid parent values
```

Shouldn't that work out of the box? As you may have already guessed, I'm new to JAGS, but I've been able to use JAGS on other models, that meaning my setup (jags + pyjags) should be fine.

Any clue?

Cheers.

Comment: What is `test`? Data? A parameter to be estimated from data? If the latter, are you providing any initial values for `test`?

Comment: `test` is a parameter that must be estimated from the data, though in this  example there is no data (I got here by simplifying a more complicated model). I had not provided any initial value for `test` because it didn't seem   necessary in previous models I tried before. However, I just tried and I get the same error. I edited the above post to show a full example (python script).

Comment: I was able to get the model to run without any errors in R, I would try removing `jags_data` from the `pyjags.Model` line to see if that makes it run.

Comment: No, removing that line doesn't help. But, you're right and it works without a hitch in R...weird. Maybe, I should report this as a bug in `pyjags`. Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: Your example worked without any error in python2.7 ... perhaps I would investigate if python3 handle `dict` differently than 2.7...

Comment: I had completely forgotten about my rant here... I did report this upstream, https://github.com/tmiasko/pyjags/issues/11 and it's being looked at